# solving for x in trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

Say you had the equation:

$$\frac{5 \cos(x)}{ \cos(2x)} = \frac{2 \sqrt{10}\cos(45^\circ-x)}{\sin(2x)}$$

how would you go about solving for **x**?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: $$ \cos(ax) = \frac{e^{iax} + e^{-iax}}{2}$$

$$ \sin(ax) = \frac{e^{iax} - e^{-iax}}{2i}$$

Then let $z = e^{ix}$ and solve as a polynomial in $z$

Comment: The first step is multiplying with $\cos(2x)\sin(2x)$ to get rid of the denominators. Then, some trigonometric idendities should help.

Comment: The $45$ seems to indicate that degree is used , but usually functions are taken in radians. What is the case here ?

Comment: @Peter degrees are used.

Comment: I would type the equation into Maple and see what comes out.

Comment: Clearing denominators, the question boils down to solving
$$ 10\sin(x)\cos^2(x) = \sqrt{20}\cos(2x)\left(\cos(x)+\sin(x)\right) $$
or
$$ \sin(x)\left[(1-4\sqrt{5})\cos^2(x)+2\sqrt{5}\right]=\sqrt{20}\cos(x)(2\cos^2(x)-1).$$
By squaring both sides and setting $z=\cos(x)$, we have to deal with
$$ (1-z^2)\left[(1-4\sqrt{5})z^2+2\sqrt{5}\right]^2 = 20 z^2(2z^2-1)^2 $$
i.e. to deal with the bicubic polynomial
$$ -380+1500 z^2+4 \sqrt{5} z^2-1439 z^4-12 \sqrt{5} z^4-81 z^6+8 \sqrt{5} z^6$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation can be rewritten as
$$
10\sin x\cos^2x=2\sqrt{5}(\cos x+\sin x)(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)
$$
Since $\cos x\ne0$ (or the right-hand side would be undefined), we can divide by $2\sqrt{5}\cos^3x$ and set $t=\tan x$, getting
$$
\sqrt{5}t=(1+t)(1-t^2)
$$
that becomes
$$
t^3+t^2+(\sqrt{5}-1)t-1=0
$$
Wolframalpha gives the following expression for the unique root:
$$
-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{16+9\sqrt{5}+3\sqrt{3(52\sqrt{5}-65)}}{2}}-
\frac{1}{3}(3\sqrt{5}-4)\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{2}{16+9\sqrt{5}+3\sqrt{3(52\sqrt{5}-65)}}}$$